# Writing a struct to flash memory

Tags: c++, c, struct, arduino, microcontroller

I am having problems writing a struct to flash memory using a microcontroller (cortex-M0 inside nrf58122 SoC).  I don't know enough c/c++ to determine if it's a memory management issue or a fundamental lack of understanding of programming.

I have a class with a struct member:

```
struct settings_t
{   
  uint16_t n;
  uint8_t b;
  bool e;
} settings;
```

In one of my class methods, I need to write the contents of this struct to flash memory in the microcontroller (no EEPROM available).  There are pre-written functions that I call in order to do this---I understand I need to erase a page before writing to it.  If I try the following:

```
settings = {
  constants::n,
  constants::b,
  constants::e
};
```

Where the values n, b, e are of the correct type, and I follow this definition by:

```
flashPageErase(PAGE_FROM_ADDRESS(constants::settingsPageAddr));
flashWriteBlock(s, &settings, sizeof(settings));
```

I get a runtime error (program execution halts, don't have an error code for it) when the flashWriteBlock function executes.  However, if I copy the struct first:

```
settings_t cpy = settings;
flashPageErase(PAGE_FROM_ADDRESS(constants::settingsPageAddr));
flashWriteBlock(s, &cpy, sizeof(settings));
```

Then it does work.  Can anyone shed some insight into this?   I can provide more detail as needed.

Comment: What type of variable is `settings`?

Comment: `settings_t cpy = settings;` should not be valid unless there is a `typedef` somewhere.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is valid in C++

Comment: @rpattiso I see. must be some `class` related concept, right? I'm not much into `c++` though. Tx for the info. This _dual-tagging_ always confuses me.

Comment: Why do you need to write it to flash at runtime?

Comment: @immibis `settings` is a class member of type `settings_t` (struct).

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.  So that if a user modifies a setting, then it's stored in NVM thus available after a power cycle.

Comment: You should probably also specify what the error says.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to put it in EEPROM instead?

Comment: My best guess is that flashWriteBlock might demand some restrictions on the starting address of the memory chunk to read from. Multiple of 8, 16, 32 ?

Comment: Are you talking about an Arduino Uno or an Arduino Due? That is are you talking about an ATMega or an ARM Controller?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no EEPROM available on this board :(

Comment: @Oncaphillis Hmm I'll have a look, I just don't understand why making a copy of the struct inside the class method works though, how can this guarantee that the address is a multiple of 8/16/32?

Comment: @UdoKlein ARM Cortex-M0 inside an nrf58122 SoC

Comment: @user2636834 it doesn't it would be pure chance

Comment: @Oncaphillis your comment made me think about the address difference of the two.  For the struct I declare (`settings`) the address is allocated in the 0x2276 range, whereas the copy (`cpy`) is allocated in the 0x3FC0 range.  I wonder if the lower range address has some issue when we try to read from it?  I'll have a closer look at the flashWriteBlock function.

Comment: @Oncaphillis upon closer inspection, it doesn't seem to have any restrictions on the source address.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to stick one on then, via I2C.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.  Thanks, but this is not what I originally asked, is it?  I already have a solution and am trying to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation may not say it, but the implementation shows that both the source and destination must be 32-bit aligned:

```
int flashWriteBlock( void *dst, const void *src, int cb )
{
    uint32_t *d = dst;
    const uint32_t *s = src;

    /* The rest of the function snipped*/
}
```

The failure is due to the `settings` variable being 16-bit aligned. It will have to be forced to 32-bit alignment. How this is done is compiler dependent. The following example works for gcc:

```
struct settings_t
{   
  uint16_t n;
  uint8_t b;
  bool e;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (4))) settings;
```

Comment: I know this is bad SO etiquette but really wanted to thank you for your thorough explanation, and helping me (and hopefully others) understand better programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an Arduino Uno and related ATMega based controllers you might want to consult the official Arduino Website: [Reading and Writing Data Structures to EEPROM](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything). The page contains templates for EEPROM_readAnything and EEPROM_writeAnything.

Comment: Sorry @UdoKlein, I added the actual ucontroller to the description. No EEPROM available :(